# Msg 195, Level 15, State 10, Line 6 'Datetime' is not a recognized built-in function name

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am getting the error while running this query

```
declare @currentDate datetime
set @currentDate = getdate()
select count(Id) 
    from dbo.tblLstOfClientHolidays 
    where Datetime(@currentDate) = CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),getdate(ClientHoldiday),10)
```

Comment: A generous gesture to accept the answer if it had helped you shows that you do care for a better world. :)

Answer (score 2):

```
Select  
    count(Id) 
From    
    dbo.tblLstOfClientHolidays 
Where   
    CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),ClientHoldiday,10) = CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),@currentDate,10)
```

Comment: thanks Mihir it worked, my bad i was using convert function once

Comment: @saumya srivastava, Feel free to accept that answer whichever you are satisfied with.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using SQL Server 2008, You can even `CONVERT` to `DATE` rather than converting to a `VARCHAR` and then doing a comparison.

```
DECLARE @currentDate DATE;
SET @currentDate = GETDATE();

SELECT count(Id) 
FROM dbo.tblLstOfClientHolidays 
WHERE CONVERT(DATE,@currentDate) = CONVERT(DATE,ClientHoldiday);
```